# Efficient method to determine location on a grid(array)

Tags: python, arrays, list, performance

I am representing a grid with a 2D list in python.  I would like to pick a point (x,y) in the list and determine it's location...right edge, top left corner, somewhere in the middle...

Currently I am checking like so:

```
         # left column, not a corner
         if x == 0 and y != 0 and y != self.dim_y - 1:
             pass
         # right column, not a corner
         elif x == self.dim_x - 1 and y != 0 and y != self.dim_y - 1:
             pass
         # top row, not a corner
         elif y == 0 and x != 0 and x != self.dim_x - 1:
             pass
         # bottom row, not a corner
         elif y == self.dim_y - 1 and x != 0 and x != self.dim_x - 1:
             pass
         # top left corner
         elif x == 0 and y == 0:
             pass
         # top right corner
         elif x == self.dim_x - 1 and y == 0:
             pass
         # bottom left corner
         elif x == 0 and y == self.dim_y - 1:
             pass
         # bottom right corner
         elif x == self.dim_x - 1 and y == self.dim_y - 1:
             pass
         # somewhere in middle; not an edge
         else:
             pass
```

Where I have some function do something after the location is determined

dim_x and dim_y are the dimensions of the list.

Is there a better way of doing this without so many if-else statements? Something efficient would be good since this part of the logic is being called a couple million times...it's for simulated annealing.

Thanks in advance.  Also, what would be a better way of wording the title?

Comment: Your fomatting is lost please edit and repost.

Comment: formatting is OK -- but you mean left column and right column, not left row and right row.

Comment: And your "top left" corner is x == 0 and y == 0 ... that would be "bottom left" in most folks' convention. Not even Antipodeans do that :-)

Comment: @John Machin: the coordinates of the top-left pixel on your screen are `x=0, y=0`. Bottom left are `x=0, y=screen_height`.

Comment: y = screen_height?? That would be either ignored or treated modulo screen_height i.e. zero :-)  Perhaps you meant (screen_height - 1). The OP mentioned neither a screen nor pixels. The usual convention with graphs on paper or a screen is that (0, 0) is the bottom-left corner.

Comment: Can this simulation be "vectorized" so that it could run in Numpy, for example, could you do 1000 of these bin determinations at the same time?  If so, it could be done much faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def location(x,y,dim_x,dim_y):
    index = 1*(y==0) + 2*(y==dim_y-1) + 3*(x==0) + 6*(x==dim_x-1)
    return ["interior","top","bottom","left","top-left",
            "bottom-left","right","top-right","bottom-right"][index]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# initially:
method_list = [
    bottom_left, bottom, bottom_right,
    left, middle, right,
    top_left, top, top_right,
    ]

# each time:
keyx = 0 if not x else (2 if x == self.dim_x - 1 else 1)
keyy = 0 if not y else (2 if y == self.dim_y - 1 else 1)
key = keyy * 3 + keyx
method_list[key](self, x, y, other_args)
```

Untested ... but the general idea should shine through.

**Update** after the goal posts were drastically relocated by "Something efficient would be good since this part of the logic is being called a couple million times...it's for simulated annealing":

Originally you didn't like the chain of tests, and said you were calling a function to handle each of the 8 cases. If you want fast (in Python): retain the chain of tests, and do the handling of each case inline instead of calling a function.

Can you use psyco? Also, consider using Cython.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a collection of coordinates (x,y) living in a grid, and you would like to know, given any coordinate, whether it is inside the grid or on an edge.

The approach I would take is to normalize the grid before making the comparison, so that its origin is (0,0) and its top right corner is (1,1), then I would only have to know the value of the coordinate to determine its location. Let me explain.

0) Let _max represent the maximum value and _min, for instance, x_min is the minimum value of the coordinate x; let _new represent the normalized value.

```
1) Given (x,y), compute: x_new = (x_max-x)/(x_max-x_min) and y_new=(y_max-y)/(y_max-y_min).

2) [this is pseudo code]
switch y_new:
  case y_new==0: pos_y='bottom'
  case y_new==1: pos_y='top'
  otherwise: pos_y='%2.2f \% on y', 100*y_new
switch x_new:
  case x_new==0: pos_x='left'
  case x_new==1: pos_x='right'
  otherwise: pos_x='%2.2f \% on x', 100*x_new

print pos_y, pos_x

It would print stuff like "bottom left" or "top right" or "32.58% on y 15.43% on x"

Hope that helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you really want to treat all these cases completely differently, your solution is okay, as it is very explicit. A compact solution might look more elegant, but will probably be harder to maintain. It really depends on what happens inside the if-blocks.

As soon as there is a common handling of, say, the corners, one might prefer to catch those cases with one clever if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be more readable / maintainable.  It will probably be a lot faster than your nested if statements since it only tests each condition once and dispatches through a dictionary which is nice and fast.

```
class LocationThing:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.dim_x = x
        self.dim_y = y

    def interior(self):
        print "interior"
    def left(self):
        print "left"
    def right(self):
        print "right"
    def top(self):
        print "top"
    def bottom(self):
        print "bottom"
    def top_left(self):
        print "top_left"
    def top_right(self):
        print "top_right"
    def bottom_left(self):
        print "bottom_left"
    def bottom_right(self):
        print "bottom_right"

    location_map = {
        # (left, right,   top, bottom)
        ( False, False, False, False ) : interior,
        (  True, False, False, False ) : left,
        ( False,  True, False, False ) : right,
        ( False, False,  True, False ) : top,
        ( False, False, False,  True ) : bottom,
        (  True, False,  True, False ) : top_left,
        ( False,  True,  True, False ) : top_right,
        (  True, False, False,  True ) : bottom_left,
        ( False,  True, False,  True ) : bottom_right,
        }


    def location(self, x,y):
        method = self.location_map[(x==0, x==self.dim_x-1, y==0, y==self.dim_y-1)]
        return method(self)

l = LocationThing(10,10)
l.location(0,0)
l.location(0,1)
l.location(1,1)
l.location(9,9)
l.location(9,1)
l.location(1,9)
l.location(0,9)
l.location(9,0)
```

When you run the above it prints

```
top_left
left
interior
bottom_right
right
bottom
bottom_left
top_right
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fast inner-loop function, you can just bite the bullet and do the ugly: nested if else statements with repeated terms, so that each comparison is only done once, and it runs about **twice as fast** as an example cleaner answer (by mobrule):

```
import timeit

def f0(x, y, x_dim, y_dim):
    if x!=0:
        if x!=x_dim: # in the x interior
            if y!=0:
                if y!=y_dim: # y interior
                    return "interior"
                else: # y==y_dim edge 'top'
                    return "interior-top"
            else:
                return "interior-bottom"
        else: # x = x_dim, "right"
            if y!=0:
                if y!=y_dim: # 
                    return "right-interior"
                else: # y==y_dim edge 'top'
                    return "right-top"
            else:
                return "right-bottom"
    else: # x=0 'left'
        if y!=0:
            if y!=y_dim: # y interior
                return "left-interior"
            else: # y==y_dim edge 'top'
                return "left-top"
        else:
            return "left-bottom"

r_list = ["interior","top","bottom","left","top-left",
            "bottom-left","right","top-right","bottom-right"]                 
def f1(x,y,dim_x,dim_y):
    index = 1*(y==0) + 2*(y==dim_y-1) + 3*(x==0) + 6*(x==dim_x-1)
    return r_list[index]

for x, y, x_dim, y_dim in [(4, 4, 5, 6), (0, 0, 5, 6)]:
    t = timeit.Timer("f0(x, y, x_dim, y_dim)", "from __main__ import f0, f1, x, y, x_dim, y_dim, r_list")
    print "f0", t.timeit(number=1000000)
    t = timeit.Timer("f1(x, y, x_dim, y_dim)", "from __main__ import f0, f1, x, y, x_dim, y_dim, r_list")
    print "f1", t.timeit(number=1000000)
```

Which gives:

```
f0 0.729887008667  # nested if-else for interior point (no "else"s)
f1 1.4765329361
f0 0.622623920441  # nested if-else for left-bottom (all "else"s)
f1 1.49259114265
```

So it's a bit better than twice as fast as mobrule's answer, which was the fastest looking code that I knew would work when I posted this.  (Also, I moved mobrule's string list out of the function as that sped up the result by 50%.)  Speed over beauty?

If instead you want a concise and easy to read solution, I suggest:

```
def f1(x, y, x_dim, y_dim):
    d_x = {0:"left", x_dim:"right"}
    d_y = {0:"bottom", y_dim:"top"}
    return d_x.get(x, "interior")+"-"+d_y.get(y, "interior")
```

which is as fast as the others by my timing.

Comment: (1) You are not using the max/dim consistently. The two functions don't produce the same results, even after adjusting for the top/bottom convention difference. (2) the fastest /looking/ code is not necessarily the fastest /running/ code. Try calculating the index by something like `(1 if not y else (2 if y == max_y else 0)) + (3 if not x else (6 if x == max_x else 0))` ... it's much more competitive (3) use `python -mtimeit -s"initialisation code" "loop code"` instead of DIY variants

Comment: 3) I think I'm using timeit in an acceptable way -- if not please post a link to where it says this is the wrong way since this is what's in the Python docs.  I'm not rolling my own, just running timeit independently with a few different points.  2) If you think yours is faster, fine, run a test and prove it; I'm happy if there's a better approach than my ugly answer.  1) if I made a typing error, fine, the point is this structure obviously works and is fast.

Comment: (3) see the Python docs -- the command line interface runs the test 3 (default) times and reports the best out of 3. (2) I'm not asserting that the index calc I mentioned above is faster than the if tests way; it's almost as good. My point was that it is much faster than mobrule's index calc. What is better depends on what the OP really wants, speed or beauty. (1) It's a braino, not a typo. Get it correct first, fast second. (4) your dict.get() effort: the OP wants to execute some unspecified code for each of the 8 cases; this code is unlikely to produce string labels.

Comment: I'm running timeit in accordance with the Python docs.  As for my codes and my possible errors, I'll let it stand, as I think it answers the question of anyone who honestly wants an answer.  I'm happy to correct errors pointed out to me, but "there's an error and I'm not going to tell you where" from someone who posts "untested" and untimed code isn't worth my time, or anyone else's for that matter.